# how to read and display a video using opencv and how to convert into frames?

Tags: video, opencv

I have got a video.I want to read and display using opencv command.(or) I have got 325 frames.how can i read and display using opencv and also how to convert those frames into video? I don't know how to write the code using opencv. is there any command for this,please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
cv::Mat img; 
cv::VideoCapture capture("yourfile.avi");
while (img.rows > 0)
{
   capture >> img;
   cv::imwrite("c:/tmp/file.png", img);
}
```

Simple enough ?